# How to retain the values displayed in the HTML after it is fetch from the PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML page that takes the user input and displays the output based on the database. I have a hyperlink to the other pages. I want when I navigate from first page to other HTML page, I add a back button and it shoud return to the first page but it should show the fetched values. Here is the code below.

1st HTML:

```
<script>
function PostData() {
var online = navigator.onLine;
if(online){
    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid").value;
    // var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 


    xhr.open('POST', 'login3.php');
    //xhr.open('POST', 'config.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("userid=" + userid + "&pid=" + pid);
    //xhr.send("&pid=" + pid);
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

}

else{
alert("You are offline");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="userid">User ID :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="userid" id="userid"  /><br/>
    <label for="pid">Password :</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pid" /><br><br/>



    <div id="div1">
    <input type="button" value ="Login" onClick="PostData()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
    $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
    $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE username = '$userid' and password = '$pid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['week'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';

    echo '<a href="2ndHTML.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';
?>
```

2nd HTML:

```
<body>

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file"  id="imageid" name="image" onchange="readURL();" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="javascript:uploadInage();" />
        <a href = "1stHTML.html">BACK</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to retain the values fetched on the 1stHTML.html

Comment: Okay, What is the problem, in the above code ?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your code is vulnerable to an [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should fix that. It also looks like you're storing passwords in plain text which is very bad practice.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen The problem is when i navigate back to the to the 1stHTML.html through the BACK button from the 2ndHTML.html, it prompts me to login again, but i want to see the value that it fetched after my first login.

Comment: then you can do like this, You should check whether the session is set in the login page, if the session is set, you can take to the home page else you can show the login form.. Do you want me to explain more (in answer) ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen please explain a bit more.

Comment: Sure writing answer ;)

Comment: You can also add the JavaScript on the back button  `<a href='javascript:window.history.back();
'>Back</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `session`. Once the user has completed the first form set a session to signal that, so when they return to the first page it will read the session and automatically redirect them to the necessary page.

You'll need to put this at the top of your `1sthtml.php` and `2ndhtml.php` page to signal that you want to use sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

On your `1sthtml.php` page you'll need to set the session information:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
    $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
    $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE username = '$userid' and password = '$pid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['week'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';

    echo '<a href="2ndHTML.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';

    // ---- SET SESSION HERE ---
    $_SESSION['stage'] = 1;
}
?>
```

And then, on the `1sthtml.php` again you'll need to check to see if that session variable exists, if it does then forward onto the page you want. So, at the top of your `1sthtml.php`, next to your previous `session_start()`:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['stage'])) {
    header('Location: 2ndhtml.php');
    exit();
}
```